# Does directly calling a Swift enum instance method create an instance?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, enums

Suppose I have an enum such as:

```
enum AnimalType {
    case Dog
    case Cat

    func barks() -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case Dog:
            return true
        case Cat:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

If I were to then do something like:

```
func pickAnimal(shouldBark: Bool) {

    switch shouldBark {

    case AnimalType.Dog.barks():
        println("you should pick dogs")

    case AnimalType.Cat.barks():
        println("you should pick cats")

    default:
        println("don't pick cats or dogs")
    }
}
```

Does calling `AnimalType.Dog.barks()` or `AnimalType.Cat.barks()` instantiate an `AnimalType`?

Comment: does `bark` call `shouldBark` or is that a typo?

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for pointing that out, I corrected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in those examples, `AnimalType.Dog.barks()` instantiates an `AnimalType`.

After all, `barks()` is an instance method. It cannot be called except by an instance.

The lifetime of the instance will be very short. Just long enough to call the `barks()` method, and that's it.

Comment: Logically yes. But from the inspection of the compiled assembly code it seems to be that  `AnimalType.Dog.barks()` is evaluated at compile time (at least in the optimized mode).

Answer (score 1):

I put together a small test project and ran it through Instruments and my findings mirror those of @martin-r. While it makes sense that a new instance of the enumeration would be created, it appears this is optimized away at compile time.

In this screenshot you can see that the only allocations performed in the method come from the use of println() for the first time:

[image: Instruments]

Comment: Interesting. But then how can the runtime evaluate the switch clauses without instantiating the enum?

Comment: But enums are value types, and for something like this without associated values, it should just be a plain integer and there should not be any "allocations" anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to "instantiate an `AnimalType`"?

Instance methods on a value type like struct or enum are resolved at compile-time, so it's equivalent to calling a static function that takes the receiver as a parameter called `self`. (Mutating methods are equivalent to an `inout` `self` parameter; non-mutating methods like `bark` are equivalent to a regular `self` parameter.) So your question is basically equivalent to asking: "**Does evaluating `barks(AnimalType.Dog)` (if there were a function `barks` that took an `AnimalType`) instantiate an `AnimalType`?**"

`AnimalType` is an enum whose cases don't have associated values. So basically it's equivalent to an integer (other than the type safety). So your question is then equivalent to asking: "**Does evaluating `barks(42)` (if there were a function `barks` that took an `Int`) instantiate an `Int`?**"

See how this is kind of a silly question? I mean, in a certain sense, inside the function, there will be a parameter, and that parameter will have type `Int`. If this is a by-value parameter, then I guess by definition a new copy of `Int` exists in the scope of that function, therefore an `Int` "was instantiated". Though the compiler will probably inline the function and optimize the parameter out anyway.